# Having problem in getting the name of people with odd group_id

Tags: mysql

I have to find the name of people who were born on Friday and Name starts with `A` or `S` and whose `group_id` is odd;

I have written the following query

```
    SELECT * FROM student 
    WHERE (group_id %2 ) = 1 
    AND student_name LIKE ("S%") OR student_name LIKE("A%") 
    AND DAYOFWEEK(date_of_birth) = 6;
```

But an even `group_id` is showing up I'm not able to understand why?

Comment: Do you mean .. AND (student_name LIKE ("S%") OR student_name LIKE("A%") ) ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the conditions:

```
student_name LIKE ("S%") OR student_name LIKE("A%")
```

inside parentheses, because the `OR` operator has lower [precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) than the `AND` operator, so your `WHERE` clause is actually setting these conditions:

```
((group_id%2)=1 AND student_name LIKE ("S%")) 
OR 
(student_name LIKE("A%") AND DAYOFWEEK(date_of_birth) =6)
```

So change to this:

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE (group_id%2)=1 
  AND (student_name LIKE ("S%") OR student_name LIKE("A%")) 
  AND DAYOFWEEK(date_of_birth) =6 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs parentheses for `OR` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE (group_id%2)=1 
AND (student_name LIKE ("S%") OR student_name LIKE("A%")) 
AND DAYOFWEEK(date_of_birth) =6 ;
```

Without that, it searches for students with

- odd group_id and name start with `A`,
- or student name starts with `S` (where group_id can be anything)

Answer (score 0):

your `sql` query should enclose the conditions in `()` to have the conditions priority right:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE (group_id%2)=1 
AND (student_name LIKE ("S%") OR student_name LIKE("A%")) 
AND DAYOFWEEK(date_of_birth) =6 ;
```